# Android TabLayout & Fragments

Tags: android

I have an Activity which contains a TabLayout and a ViewPager. The first tab contains a calendar and the second tab contains a timer.

Tapping on a date in the first tab should display a fragment with some event details while simultaneously hiding or removing that menu tab.

To this end, how can I use a FrameLayout as a fragment container when my layout already contains a ViewPager? Should I create a new Activity to get what I want, or is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Please show the code you have already.

Comment: Corrected multiple misspellings. Improved diction and flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is basically a list/details pattern. In short, yes, you should create a new activity for the details. It is the expected flow of an android app and it makes the implementation for you so much easier.